# How do I get PHP to accept ISO-8859-1 characters in general?

Tags: php, iso-8859-1, utf

This has been bugging me for ages and I want to get to the bottom of this once and for all. I have an associative array which fields I have defined using ISO-8859-1 characters. For instance:

```
array("utført" => "red");
```

I also have another array that I have loaded in from a file. I have printed this array out in a browser, checking that values like Æ, Ø and Å is intact. I try to compare two fields from these arrays and I'm slapped by the message:

> Undefined index: utfã¸rt on line 39

I can't help but sob. Every single damn time I involve any letters outside UTF-8 in a script they are at some point converted into `ã¸r` or similar nonsense.

My script file is encoded in ISO-8859-1, the document from which I'm loading my data is the same, and so is the MySQL table I'm trying to save the data to.

So the only conclusion I can draw is that PHP isn't accepting just any character-sets into it's code, and I have to somehow force PHP to speak Norwegian.

Thanks for any suggestions

*Just FYI, I won't accept any answers in the lines of "Just don't use those characters" or "Just replace those characters with UTF equivalents at file load" or any other hack solutions*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read your data from external file try to convert them in proper encoding.

Something like this I have on my mind...

```
  $f = file_get_contents('externaldata.txt');
  $f = mb_convert_encoding($f, 'iso-8859-1');
  // from this point deal with $f whatever you want
```

Also, look at [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) manual for more info.

Comment: I had to specify that I was converting from UTF-8 `mb_convert_encoding($cell->getValue(), "iso-8859-1", "UTF-8")` before it would work, but thanks! I suspect that PHPExcel only reads data as UTF-8 regardless of file encoding

Comment: I use this function every time I stuck with different encoding. It helps in almost every situation. About PHPExcel, I don't know but you can check out their official documentation [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).